# How to make document.body.onmousedown = ContextMouseDown; work in the other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html

The lines below work in IE, what do I have to do so that it works in the other browsers?

```
document.body.onmousedown = ContextMouseDown;
document.body.oncontextmenu = ContextShow;
```

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in firefox, assuming that you don't call these until your page is loaded:

```
<script>
function ContextMouseDown() {
    alert('mousedown');
}

function ContextShow() {
    alert('contextshow');
}

function loadstuff() {
    document.body.onmousedown = ContextMouseDown;
    document.body.oncontextmenu = ContextShow;
}
</script>
```

The important part:

```
<body onload="loadstuff()">
```